# Why does Closure Compiler not shorten this?

Tags: javascript, minify, google-closure-compiler

I'm not sure whether this is just a bug or an intended feature.

Basically, I have this tiny function (I now see `end` is colored blue here but this works just fine, if I rename it to something else I still have the issue):

```
function f(a, b) {
    var start = Math.min(a, b);
    var end = Math.max(a, b);

    tb.selectionStart = start;
    tb.selectionEnd = end;
};
```

When closure-compiling it, I get:

```
function f(a,b){var c=Math.max(a,b);tb.selectionStart=Math.min(a,b);tb.selectionEnd=c};
```

However, why is `selectionStart` set to `Math.min` directly, whilst `selecitonEnd` is set to a variable (`c`), which is declared first? Isn't it shorter to do `tb.selectionEnd=Math.max(a,b)`?

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Just as a side note, the SO syntax highlighter is a catch-all kind of thing. It will try its best to highlight any language. So it doesn't exactly detect JS, just a C syntax, and colors common keywords. Also, you can output a pretty-printed version of your code, that makes it more readable for seeing what closure compiler is up to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT: THERE IS AN "OFFICIAL" ANSWER IN THIS LINK: 
https://web.archive.org/web/20151226143155/http://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/issues/detail?id=410**

I think an assignment to a variable, followed immediately by usage of that variable, can be inlined.  However, if there is any statement in between that cannot be proven to be free of side-effects, then the compiler won't inline it.

In your case, assignment to variable "start" is separated from the usage of "start" only by the assignment statement to "end".  However, this statement is free of side-effects since Math.max is an internal function and the compiler knows that it is side-effect-free.

However, in your case, assignment to variable "end" is separated from the usage of that variable by a statement, which is an assignment of "start" to a property.  Now, I believe that the compiler does not assume that merely assigning to a property is always side-effect-free; that is because some properties, when assigned, actually cause different behavior, or change global state (such as RegExp).  In some systems, property assignments actually trigger certain system-specific features (e.g. hardware interface) that may in-turn contain side-effects.

That is why, sometimes, when you have code like this:

```
foo.bar = 1;
foo.bar = 2;
foo.bar = 3;
```

The compiler won't eliminate the first two statements since assignment to "bar" may have side effects.

So, in your question, the variable "end" cannot be inlined because the statement `tb.selectionStart = start;` may have side effects (perhaps only in wierd cases).

**If you make "tb" a local variable, or something that the compiler has complete control of (e.g. a simple object: `var tb = {};`), then you'll find that the compiler inlines all of the assignments just fine.**

Comment: I see, but couldn't the compiler possibly be optimized in such a way that `Math.max` is seen as creating no side effects?

Comment: Math.max is a JS internal function and has no side effects.  This is in the compiler's externs file.  However, your assignment to tb.selectionStart is not guaranteed to have no side-effects.  An assignment to a var can only be inlined if there is no statement between the assignment and the usage that may potentially contain side-effects.

Comment: Oh, I understand now. Wasn't aware of getters/setters that can do things when used too.

Comment: You can prove this by the following experiment: 1) remove the wrapper function, 2) remove "var" in front of "start" and "end" (thus making them global variables), 3) compile.  You'll find that, surprise!, the compiler does not remove either "start" nor "end".  That's because a global variable is accessible by all functions, and as long as there is **something** that can *potentially* contains side-effects, it can access these global variables!  So the compiler must leave them alone.

Comment: Think in terms of "tb.selectionStart" turning on some hardware system feature -- JS is not limited to being run in a browser, you know -- and it accesses the "start" and "end" variables.  You get the idea -- a side effect.  Of course, this is a very nasty way to write programs, but the compiler must be conservative and assume that we all write dangerous code to shoot ourselves.

Comment: I did the following experiment where using the same expression twice results in a different result: http://jsfiddle.net/MCXWw/. So I see it does matter - the closure compiler just doesn't know the fine details of the environment (i.e. that it doesn't matter in the code of my question).

Comment: 1) Closure Compiler does not support ES5.  So your getters and setters are not supposed to be working right.  2) In your code, it is the "tb" that is the culprit.  If "tb" refers to a global variable, or something UI-related, then it will assume that it can contain side-effects (it is probably a textbox).  If you define "var tb = {};" ahead, then the compiler will know that tb.selectionStart cannot have side effects and will optimize the whole thing away.

Comment: It is really a problem of a data dependency. The last example on the defect I think makes it clear.

Answer (score 3):

if you paste this code, this works.

```
function f(a, b) {
    var start = Math.min(a, b);
    tb.selectionStart = start;

    var end = Math.max(a, b);
    tb.selectionEnd = end;
};
```

`function f(a,b){tb.selectionStart=Math.min(a,b);tb.selectionEnd=Math.max(a,b)};`

i this is a mistake by closure compiler.

Comment: I can reproduce this, whilst my or your order shouldn't make any difference. Well, I guess there is nothing to do against it.

Comment: i submitted this topic to closure compiler project page. hope this will fixed.
http://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/issues/detail?id=410

Comment: Thanks very much. It's great you did that.

Comment: I think it is a matter of side effects -- see my answer.