# Why won't Google Closure Compiler inline this intermediate variable assignment?

Tags: javascript, minify, google-closure-compiler

I'm using Google Closure Compiler in Advanced mode. I have a piece of code that assigns the return value of a global function to a variable, then immediately uses the value of the variable once only. For simplicity's sake, imagine it's this ([try it yourself in the Closure Compiler Service](https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home#code%3D%252F%252F%2520%253D%253DClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540output_file_name%2520default.js%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540compilation_level%2520ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS%250A%252F%252F%2520%253D%253D%252FClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%250A(function%2520()%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520var%2520thingIWantToName%2520%253D%2520mysteriousGlobalFunction()%250A%2520%2520console.log(thingIWantToName)%250A%257D)())):

```js
(function () {
  var thingIWantToName = mysteriousGlobalFunction()
  console.log(thingIWantToName)
})()
```

I would expect the code to be minified into something like this, Exhibit A:

```js
console.log(mysteriousGlobalFunction())
```

Instead it gets minified into code that retains the intermediate `var` declaration, Exhibit B:

```js
var a=mysteriousGlobalFunction();console.log(a);
```

I understand that Closure Compiler can't guarantee that `mysteriousGlobalFunction()` is free of side effects without seeing the implementation, and nor can it know that it doesn't rely on global state. I can understand why it wouldn't remove the variable assignment [if there was another statement in between](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5565500/why-does-closure-compiler-not-shorten-this/), or if the variable were used again.

But in this case, I'm struggling to see what could possibly happen in `mysteriousGlobalFunction()` that would make Exhibit A !== Exhibit B, in terms of execution order or anything else. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is this causing a problem for you, or is this more a curiousity question?  The compiler team might have some specific answer, but I'm guessing the answer is just "the compiler isn't perfect".